# Calculator App : The app shuts down after I click on a (sign)button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator

I cant figure out where I went wrong with my code. Every time I press a button my apps shuts down unless I add a try and catch. As soon as I enter the two numbers and add the sign, the results should print out, but instead the app is just shutting down. Here is my LogCat and code. BTW I'm new to java & android studio, so excuse my mistakes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    Button btnAdd, btnSubtract,btnMultiply, btnDivide;
    TextView textResults, textSigns;
    EditText firstnumber, secondnumber;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnumber);
        secondnumber =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondnumber);
        textResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
        textSigns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invisible_signs);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        btnDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
        btnMultiply =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Multiply);
        btnSubtract =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Subtract);
        final String number1 = firstnumber.getText().toString();
        final String number2 = secondnumber.getText().toString();


        btnDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {int divide = Integer.parseInt(number1) / Integer.parseInt(number2);
                    textResults.setText(number1 + " / " + number2  );
                    textResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textResults.append("\n" + divide);}
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Divide These Numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

            }
        });

        btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int multiply = Integer.parseInt(number1) * Integer.parseInt(number2);
                textResults.setText(number1 + " * " + number2  );
                textResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textResults.append("\n" + multiply);
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int addition = Integer.parseInt(number1) + Integer.parseInt(number2);
                textResults.setText(number1 + " + " + number2  );
                textResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textResults.append("\n" + addition);
            }
        });

        btnSubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int subtract = Integer.parseInt(number1) - Integer.parseInt(number2);
                textResults.setText(number1 + " - " + number2  );
                textResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textResults.append("\n" + subtract);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

.
Logcat:

```
 0-25 16:12:28.330 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-25 16:12:28.640 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
10-25 16:12:28.640 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-25 16:12:29.680 1860-1872/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20ms
10-25 16:12:29.680 1860-1872/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 371(64KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 47% free, 556KB/1068KB, paused 20ms total 280ms
10-25 16:12:30.370 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 40ms
10-25 16:12:30.620 1860-1900/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
10-25 16:12:30.690 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fc39eccf580, tid 1860
10-25 16:12:30.690 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-25 16:12:30.870 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 100ms
10-25 16:12:30.890 1860-1872/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 824(47KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 919KB/1068KB, paused 0 total 160ms
10-25 16:12:30.940 1860-1872/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 50ms
10-25 16:12:31.300 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms
10-25 16:12:31.540 1860-1872/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 437(19KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 942KB/1068KB, paused 0 total 240ms
10-25 16:12:31.680 1860-1900/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-25 16:12:31.720 1860-1900/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-25 16:12:31.760 1860-1900/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-25 16:12:31.760 1860-1900/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fc39ece3040, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-25 20:12:38.850 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 220ms
10-25 20:12:39.010 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-25 20:12:39.790 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-25 16:12:42.610 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30ms
10-25 16:12:42.940 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-25 16:12:43.120 1860-1900/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-25 16:12:43.120 1860-1900/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fc3a5ff6fc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-25 16:12:49.020 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 150ms
10-25 16:12:49.380 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 80ms
10-25 16:12:58.690 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp, PID: 1860
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
10-25 16:12:58.770 1860-1860/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
10-25 16:13:05.160 1860-1867/com.squarespace.atpublishing.calculatorapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 250ms
```

Comment: **Invalid int: ""**???

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` You can't treat **""** as if it was an integer **number**.

Comment: Note that the `Integer.parseInt()` method throws a `NumberFormatException` (what you're seeing here) if "`String` cannot be passed as an integer value" - from the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: Got it working. Thanks you all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines

```
final String number1 = firstnumber.getText().toString();
final String number2 = secondnumber.getText().toString();
```

And adjust this one

```
int divide = Integer.parseInt(firstnumber.getText()) / Integer.parseInt(secondnumber.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't read the values of the inputs when doing calculations, so the strings will be always empty.

Variables get their values when assigned, the assignment doesn't mean they're bound to the inputs and change their values when the inputs change.